# MySQL Query to MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I'm 'translating' a PHP application and I have some doubts about this mySql Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.foo) FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 WHERE t1.foo_id=t2.foo
```

How can I translate this into mongo?

Comment: [MongoDB does "not" do joins](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is: you don't. Mongo is not relational, so there is no unambigous, straightforward way to translate relational data to document-based datasets.

You are using a (implicit) join to query a relation, that spans over 2 tables. This is definitly not possible in Mongo. You could however create a [map/reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)-based scheme and view for your data, or use linked / embedded documents, but that really depends on your datasets.

Here is a little link to a [comparision](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) between Mongo and SQL.

Comment: mapReduce is "not" a replacement for joins in any way. There are only "specific" cases where an "incremental mapReduce" can be used to "combne" datasets, but this is seperate operations and requires an output collection. If you don't really know anything about the topic then comment only ( with helpful links ) rather than try to submit an answer.